# XSD schema handling one of two values

Tags: xml, xsd, switch-statement

I am creating an xsd schema to support the following xml structure:

```
<Switch code="enable'>
 .....more..stuff.....
</Switch>
```

Here is how it is declared in the schema

```
 <xs:element name="Switch minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
      <xs:complexType>
         ................
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="Code" use="required"/>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

Now the value of Switch code can only be either "enable" or "disable". In my xsd schema how would i specify that it could only either one of those values? Is that possible or do i need to use a programming language such as C# to handle this?

I would greatly appreciate if someone could assist me please.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Ian answer ... or also directly without declaring a named type:

```
<xs:element name="Switch" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
  <xs:complexType>
     ................
    <xs:attribute name="Code" use="required">
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:enumeration value="enable" />
          <xs:enumeration value="disable" />
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: Actually, this is declaring a type; it just isn't giving it a name.

Answer (score 2):

You can define enumerated types in XML schema:

```
<xs:simpleType name="enableDisable">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:enumeration value="enable" />
    <xs:enumeration value="disable" />
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

With that in place you can use this type instead of `xs:string` for the attribute

```
<xs:attribute type="enableDisable" name="Code" use="required"/>
```

(it may need a prefix if your schema has a `targetNamespace`)